# How to add dynamic id for each query in jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm using Jooq 3.10. I'd like to add default condition with dynamic value for each and every select, update and delete query.

Example 1:

`select * from table_name;`

`select * from table_name where org_id = dynamic_value`

Example 2:

`select * from table_name where column_name = value;`

`select * from table_name where column_name = value and org_id = dynamic_value`

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solving this using jOOQ

This looks like a case for row level security, which can be implemented using a [`VisitListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/VisitListener.html) as explained here:
https://blog.jooq.org/2015/06/17/implementing-client-side-row-level-security-with-jooq

The concrete implementation is too complex to reproduce here on Stack Overflow, but it's exactly what you need, if you're looking for a jOOQ-only solution.

#### Solving this using SQL

Not all databases support this, but it's worth mentioning here:

A more thorough solution would be to resort to using SQL views or table valued functions and to add the relevant predicate directly to those views or functions.

- In the case of using views, you'll have to use something like Oracle's `SYS_CONTEXT` function, initialising your JDBC connection with the relevant `dynamic_value` at the beginning of the transaction.
- In the case of using table valued functions, you can pass the `dynamic_value` directly to that function, which then runs the query on the underlying table, adding the predicate.

In both of the above cases, you would have to make sure not to give any grants to the tables directly, but only to the views.